# #1054 - Unknown column 'trelsucompon.sunum' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

I am new writing queries and this error seems so general I am having trouble to find an answer.  I have two SQL queries that work separately and I want to combine them into one query:

```
SELECT tblStruct.Site, tblStruct.SUNum, tlkpSUDesc.SUDesc, 
tblStruct.LenActl, tblStruct.LenInf, tblStruct.LenBasis, 
tblStruct.WidActl, tblStruct.WidInf, tblStruct.WidBasis, 
tblStruct.HtActl, tblStruct.HtInf, tblStruct.HtBasis, 
tblStruct.DepActll, tblStruct.DepInf, tblStruct.DepBasis, 
tblStruct.Constr, tblStruct.RoofSupport, tblStruct.RoofComm, tblStruct.Axis,
tblcompon.site, tblcompon.datebegin, tblcompon.dateend, trelsucompon.sunum, trelsucompon.componid
FROM tlkpSUDesc
RIGHT JOIN (tblSU 
 RIGHT JOIN tblStruct ON (tblSU.SUNum = tblStruct.SUNum) 
  AND (tblSU.Site = tblStruct.Site)) ON tlkpSUDesc.SUDescCode = tblSU.SUDescCode
LEFT JOIN tblcompon on tblcompon.site = trelsucompon.site AND tblcompon.componid = trelsucompon.componid
WHERE tblStruct.Site IN ('5MT123') AND tblcompon.datebegin >= 600 AND tblcompon.dateend <= 1200
ORDER By tblStruct.Site, tblStruct.SUNum ASC
```

and

```
SELECT tblcompon.site, tblcompon.datebegin, tblcompon.dateend, trelsucompon.sunum, trelsucompon.componid
    FROM trelsucompon   
    LEFT JOIN tblcompon on tblcompon.site = trelsucompon.site AND tblcompon.componid = trelsucompon.componid       
    WHERE tblcompon.site = '5MT10684' AND tblcompon.datebegin >= 600 AND tblcompon.dateend <= 1200
```

I tried to combine them and I get that error.

```
SELECT tblStruct.Site, tblStruct.SUNum, tlkpSUDesc.SUDesc, 
tblStruct.LenActl, tblStruct.LenInf, tblStruct.LenBasis, 
tblStruct.WidActl, tblStruct.WidInf, tblStruct.WidBasis, 
tblStruct.HtActl, tblStruct.HtInf, tblStruct.HtBasis, 
tblStruct.DepActll, tblStruct.DepInf, tblStruct.DepBasis, 
tblStruct.Constr, tblStruct.RoofSupport, tblStruct.RoofComm, tblStruct.Axis,
tblcompon.site, tblcompon.datebegin, tblcompon.dateend, trelsucompon.sunum, 
trelsucompon.componid
FROM tlkpSUDesc
RIGHT JOIN (tblSU 
 RIGHT JOIN tblStruct ON (tblSU.SUNum = tblStruct.SUNum) 
  AND (tblSU.Site = tblStruct.Site)) ON tlkpSUDesc.SUDescCode = tblSU.SUDescCode
LEFT JOIN tblcompon on tblcompon.site = trelsucompon.site AND tblcompon.componid = trelsucompon.componid
WHERE tblStruct.Site IN ('5MT123')  AND tblcompon.datebegin >= 540  AND tblcompon.dateend <= 650
ORDER By tblStruct.Site, tblStruct.SUNum ASC
```

This is the error:
#1054 - Unknown column 'trelsucompon.sunum' in 'field list'.

That column is in the other query as are the others which is why it doesn't make sense.

Comment: *`.. FROM tlkpSUDesc RIGHT JOIN tblSU RIGHT JOIN tblStruct LEFT JOIN tblcompon ..`* There is no `trelsucompon` table in the query data source, there exists `tblcompon` only. A typo?

Comment: @Akina I'm not sure what you mean.  I did have a typo in the query that worked, is was missing an 'n'... FROM trelsucompon  Other than that both queries work sapartely, i just need to combine them.

Comment: *I'm not sure what you mean.* Copy your last query to text editor. Find all `trelsucompon` substring occurences. Try to find those occurence which is table (datasource) name and not a part of column name. I see only 4 occurences - 2 in the output list and 2 in ON clause, and none as table name in FROM.

Comment: *Why is this getting downvoted?* I think it's because of the sloppy formatting.

Comment: I will try and do what you suggested to see if I can get it to work.  Also, I am not sure how to fix the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use both queries as as subqueries.

You need to check which JOIN you actually need

```
SELECT tblStruct1.Site, tblStruct1.SUNum, tblStruct1.SUDesc, 
   tblStruct1.LenActl, tblStruct1.LenInf, tblStruct1.LenBasis, 
   tblStruct1.WidActl, tblStruct1.WidInf, tblStruct1.WidBasis, 
   tblStruct1.HtActl, tblStruct1.HtInf, tblStruct1.HtBasis, 
   tblStruct1.DepActll, tblStruct1.DepInf, tblStruct1.DepBasis, 
   tblStruct1.Constr, tblStruct1.RoofSupport, tblStruct1.RoofComm, tblStruct1.Axis,
tblcompon1.site tc_site, tblcompon1.datebegin, tblcompon1.dateend, tblcompon1.sunum
, tblcompon1.componid
FROM
(SELECT tblStruct.Site, tblStruct.SUNum, tlkpSUDesc.SUDesc, 
   tblStruct.LenActl, tblStruct.LenInf, tblStruct.LenBasis, 
   tblStruct.WidActl, tblStruct.WidInf, tblStruct.WidBasis, 
   tblStruct.HtActl, tblStruct.HtInf, tblStruct.HtBasis, 
   tblStruct.DepActll, tblStruct.DepInf, tblStruct.DepBasis, 
   tblStruct.Constr, tblStruct.RoofSupport, tblStruct.RoofComm, tblStruct.Axis
FROM tlkpSUDesc
RIGHT JOIN (tblSU 
    RIGHT JOIN tblStruct ON (tblSU.SUNum = tblStruct.SUNum) 
        AND (tblSU.Site = tblStruct.Site)) ON tlkpSUDesc.SUDescCode = tblSU.SUDescCode
WHERE tblStruct.Site IN ('5MT123')) tblStruct1
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT tblcompon.site, tblcompon.datebegin, tblcompon.dateend, trelsucompon.sunum, trelsucompon.componid
    FROM trelsucompo        
    LEFT JOIN tblcompon on tblcompon.site = trelsucompon.site AND tblcompon.componid = trelsucompon.componid       
    WHERE tblcompon.site = '5MT10684' AND tblcompon.datebegin >= 600 AND tblcompon.dateend <= 1200
) tblcompon1 ON tblcompon1.site = tblstruct1.site
ORDER By tblStruct1.Site, tblStruct1.SUNum ASC
```

Comment: I ran that and I get the same kind of error - #1054 - Unknown column 'trelsucompon1.sunum' in 'field list'

Comment: copy it again. there was a typo, there are a lot of column so one get get by

Comment: I re-copied the query, although I don't at the moment see what changed, and it returned results.  But I don't get any dates with the results.

Comment: i changed the table Prefix of sunum, you could try it with right join, but without any data, i can not debug it, so you have to do it

Comment: Can you explain your solution?  I was able to get it to work as there was another typo in what I originally posted, but now I need to refine it.  So any explanation you can provide so I can tweak this would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: it  is  not complicated, as i said your two queries produce two resultsets (tables again),which can be joined like any other table, only  that we use them as subqueries. Now we access all columns from both subqueries which we put in the select

Comment: A light went off when I re-read the comments.  Thanks!